# average of 2 neighbouring elements in array python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to write a program to print if an element in an array is the average of its 2 neighbours. Say I have an array consisting of `[1,3,5,7,12,21]` -- 3 is the average of 1+5 and 5 is the average of 3+7.
I'm using `for i in arr:` with `if i>arr[0] and i<arr[-1]` inside it and `if i == (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])/2:` inside that. Except when i try to run it, it says index out of range... I'm assuming it's because `i-1` goes under `arr[0]` and `i+1` goes above `arr[-1]` but I thought if I put in the condition `if i>arr[0] and i<arr[-1]` it won't count both of them.
How do I go about this code otherwise? my code:

```
arr = []
while True:
    x = input("Enter numbers, type ''STOP'' to stop.\n")
    if x.upper() == "STOP":
        break
    x=int(x)
    arr.append(x)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if 0 < i < len(arr)-1:
        if arr[i] == (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])//2:
            print(arr[i], "is the average of its neighbours")
```

Comment: Please update your question to include your code as well. It will help to understand the issue at hand.

Comment: just did, still dont know how to edit it correctly so sorry about that...

Comment: Provide the input and the expected output.

Comment: By mistake, I have edited the original question and modified the code in question. Kindly do not approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem at this line `if i == (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])/2`. Here you are checking if the item is the average of the items at the index of `(current value -1)` and the `(current value + 1)`. So let's say when we are checking for 3, we are checking indices `arr[3-1]` and `arr[3+1]`. This should be safe for now. But in the next iteration for 7, you are checking `arr[7-1]` and `arr[7+1]`, `arr[8]` does not exist. Thus it is throwing `index out of range`.

Thus instead of iterating through the list items you need to iterate through list indices and access list items using the index. The loop will look something like below code:

```
arr = [1,3,5,7,12,21]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if 0 < i < len(arr)-1:
        if arr[i] == (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])//2:
            print(arr[i], "is the average of its neighbours")
```

It prints

```
3 is the average of its neighbours
5 is the average of its neighbours
```

Comment: I have tried doing range but i guess what I really needed for it to work was //2 instead of /2, thanks a lot for everyone who answered also! Real life savers out here!

Comment: It should work even with `/` division in python 3. Please bear in mind that `3//2=1`. This might give erroneous result sometime

Comment: understand, also I have a question, you wrote if 0 < i < len(arr)-1: , how does it know 0 and len(arr)-1 are the first and last elements in array if it's just numbers?

Comment: Here `i` is not an item in the list but the indices. So `0 < i < len(arr)-1` it is checking if an index is greater than `zero` (corresponding to first item in the list) and less than `len(arr)-1` (corresponding to last item in the list). If it is then we can proceed with checking of element at the current index is the average of the previous and next item (again accessed by index `i - 1` and `i +1` respectively.

Comment: As some have already mentioned in their answers, we can skip this condition checking entirely by using `range(1, len(arr)-1)`. That way we will start the loop from the second index `(index = 1)` and stop at the second last index (in this case `index = 4`) That would be more efficient using less CPU cycles overall to complete the execution.

Answer (score 1):

In the condition `if i == (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])/2:` i is value of an array item not index. So when i become 12 or 21 it gets out of the index range of arr. Instead you can use `for i in range(len(arr)):` to get the index.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below

```
lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 21, 11, 12, 13]
for idx in range(1, len(lst) - 1):
    if lst[idx] == (lst[idx - 1] + lst[idx + 1]) / 2:
        print(f'{lst[idx]} is AVG of {lst[idx - 1]} and {lst[idx + 1]}')
```

output

```
3 is AVG of 1 and 5
5 is AVG of 3 and 7
12 is AVG of 11 and 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the length of the array to create a check. Try this

```
size = len(arr)
for indx, i in enumerate(some):
    if indx >0:
        if indx < size-1:
            val = (arr[indx-1]+ arr[indx+1])//2
            print(f'{val} is the average of its neighbours' )
```